# Magento: Display Level specific categories of currenty category tree

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to display a menu in my magento shop which displays only level 3 categories of the current category tree i am in.

my category tree splits into two paths:

- Default

  - Sale

    - Item 1
    - Item 2
  - Repair

    - Item 1
    - Item 2

I would like to display only level 3 of sale when i am in any of the sale categories and vice-versa when I am any of the repair category.

The code below displays level 3 categories but only for Repair regardless in which category I happen to be in.

```
<?php 
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');

    /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $categories = $layer->getCurrentCategory();


$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
          ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())                     
                     ->getCollection()
                     // magic is prepared here..
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     // then the magic happens here:
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq' => 3))
                     ->load();
  ?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $cat): ?>
```

Thanks.

Mod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution by using parentid filtering, this is the code I added:

```
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$curent_cat = $_cat->getCurrentCategory();
$curent_cat_id = $curent_cat->getId();


$parentId=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($curent_cat_id)->getParentId();
```

then I filter the parentId using add attribute filter: this displays me only level 3 categories which are subcategories of the parentid(root ID) of this category. (format edit)

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')

                     ->getCollection()

                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

                      ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq' => 3))
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $parentId))

                     ->load();
```